# Adjective to describe the classification of a result as true/false positive/negative

Tags: single-word-requests

I am performing experiments where results can be classified as true positive, true negative, false positive, or false negative. Is there a good word for this kind of classification?

I have considered just using "classification". I also considered something like "error type", as in Type I or Type II error, but I find it misleading since the result might not actually be an error.

Example usage:

> "The ___ of the experiment was true negative".

Comment: `Truth value`, though not strictly applicable, could be used to get your meaning across.

Comment: What's wrong with `the result/outcome of the experiment...`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use «result» as in your example? If this works, you might also want to consider «outcome».

Comment: Both suggestions are good, in my opinion, but do you mean to say "If this **doesn't work**" rather than "If this works" in your second sentence?

Comment: If «result» does not work semantically, «outcome» probably would not work either. But if it does, which word to chose is a matter of taste.

Comment: The "result" of the experiment says whether the test was positive or negative, but not whether that result was correct or not